Ошибка TypeError: a.createContext is not a function
Перевел проект с React на React+Next+Typescript. При запуске в контейнере Docker на этапе создания билда появляется ошибка:
TypeError: a.createContext is not a function

Поиск информации, в основном, выдает о необходимости установки "use client", то есть использование клиентских компонентов. Поставил везде, где используются хуки и контекст "use client", ошибка не пропадает.
Создание контекста:
"use client"

import React from "react";
import { User } from "../components/App/App"

const defaultState = {
    name: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
    _id: undefined,
};

export const CurrentUserContext = React.createContext<User>(defaultState);

Использование в компоненте с роутами:
<CurrentUserContext.Provider value={currentUser as User}>
...
</CurrentUserContext.Provider>

Извлечение данных из контекста:
import { CurrentUserContext } from "../../contexts/CurrentUserContext";
...
const currentUser = React.useContext(CurrentUserContext);


без докера запускается? Если npm start запустить вручную, падает ошибка?

Нет, появляется другая ошибка: Error: Failed to collect page data for /
at C:\Users\Zaytsev\dev\movies-explorer-typescript\movies-explorer-frontend\node_modules\next\dist\build\utils.js:1268:15
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
type: 'Error'
}
